# Counting the occurrences of a string in each file

Tags: java, strings, file, search

I am trying to find a phrase or a string in file and count the number of occurrences of that string:

```
 private static HashMap<String, Integer> bruteForceSearch(
      String stringToLookFor, List<File> list) throws IOException {

    HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (File file : list) {
      String fileName = file.getName();
      // System.out.println(fileName);
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
      String readLine = "";
      int count = 0;
      while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = readLine.split(" ");
        for (String text : words) {
          if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(stringToLookFor)) {
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
      if (count != 0) {
        result.put(fileName, count);
      }

      in.close();
    }

    return result;

  }
```

Are there any improvements to do in my code? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

- The first comment is that your code doesn't handle exceptions at all. You open a `FileInputStream` but you do not close it in case of exceptions. This can lead to a [resource leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_leak). Beginning with Java 7, you can use the [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to make sure that all open streams are closed properly. Instead of having

  ```
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
  ```

  you would have

  ```
  try (FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
  ) {
      // do the rest here
  }
  ```

  When the `try` block will finish, whether normally or exceptionally, all the streams that were opened in the `try` initialization block will be closed.
- You don't need to wrap your stream into a `InputStreamReader` and a `FileInputStream`. You can just use a `FileReader` that does this already, turning your code into

  ```
  try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
      // do the rest here
  }
  ```

  When the `BufferedReader` will be closed, it will also close the underlying `FileReader`.
- You should prefer to [program against interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1743880) and not implementation. Consider changing this

  ```
  HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  ```

  to this

  ```
  Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  ```

  or even

  ```
  Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
  ```

  since you don't need to reiterate the type parameters since Java 7. In the same way, your method could return a `Map<String, Integer>` instead of a `HashMap<String, Integer>`.
- Try to remove commented out code like `// System.out.println(fileName);`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

- Your `in.close()` method is not placed in `finally` block, which means when exception will be thrown before this line, `in` will not be closed.
  Simplest way to correct it is to use try-with-resources which automatically adds code responsible for closing resource opened by this block.

Improvements:

- Don't limit yourself to only HashMap. You should try to ["program to an interface"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) which will give you more flexibility and allow you to switch to other map if needed. So use `Map<String, Integer>` as reference and methods return type.
- If you want to read file by words instead of `readLine`/`split(" ")` combination use `Scanner` and its `next()` method which by default will return tokens split on one or more whitespaces. This will also allow you to skip all this `BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(FileInputStream))` decoration headache.
- You are using `fileName` in one place so you don't really need this line `String fileName = file.getName();` and instead of `result.put(fileName, count);` you can simply write `result.put(file.getName(), count);`
- Consider renaming your `list` into something more descriptive like `files`

So your code can look more like:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> bruteForceSearch(String stringToLookFor,
        List<File> files) throws IOException {

    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (File file : files) {
        int count = 0;
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {//will close Scanner automatically
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                if (sc.next().equals(stringToLookFor)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count != 0) {
            result.put(file.getName(), count);
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

- to simplify your code you can separate it even more. You can add method which will return number of founded words in single file and use this method inside your bruteForceSearch

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first answer.